# CryptEncodeObjectEx segfault при обращении

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-10, cryptoapi

CryptEncodeObjectEx разваливается при обращении, параметры не влияют, как выяснилось.Собираю gcc-tdm, через Code::Blocks, что опробовано:

1. Удалил родной для gcc crypt32.a, так как подозреваю что он довольно старый, прицепил в опциях линкера напрямую файл windows/system32/crypt32.dll
   1.1 Тоже самое проделал для advapi.a
2. На всякий случай вставил флаг -Lwinsdk/lib/../x86
3. Перепроверил декларацию этой функции, взяв ее с сайта микрософт.

Все шаги не изменили поведение, код примерно следующий:

```
CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
        PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, pPrivKeyBLOB, 0, NULL, NULL, &size);
```

То есть никаких серьезных действий, только получить размер..

При сборке пишет следующий warning:

```
Warning: resolving _CryptEncodeObjectEx@28 by linking to _CryptEncodeObjectEx
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
```

В Call stack примерно такая картина при segfault :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие есть мысли по этому поводу?
Win10, последний билд.

**P.S.**

Переставил gcc 8.10 i686-w64-mingw32, результат несколько изменился но примерно тоже самое.
Для независимого теста нашел на гитхабе [проектик](https://github.com/odzhan/rsa) где активно используется CryptEncodeObjectEx и есть уже скомпилированный вариант. Собранный автором работает, собранный мной нет. Приложение проходит 22 цикла в функции CryptEncodeObjectEx и вылетает...

Вот значимые части прохождения функции CryptEncodeObjectEx дебагером:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог GDB:

```
Child process PID: 7720
At rsa.c:474
At rsa.c:477
В CryptStringToBinaryA () (C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll)
#4  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#4  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#5  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#5  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlUnwind () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#4  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#4  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlImageNtHeaderEx () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlUnwind () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#8  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#8  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddressEx () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddressEx () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddressEx () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddressEx () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlRetrieveNtUserPfn () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#7  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlUnwind () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlImageNtHeaderEx () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
В ntdll!RtlUnwind () (C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
At rsa.c:477
#6  0x00401f27 in RSA_write_key (ctx=0x21298, ofile=0x40536d "public.pem", pemType=1) at rsa.c:477
rsa.c:477:11635:beg:0x401f27
[Inferior 1 (process 7720) exited normally]
Отладчик завершился со статусом 0
```

nm при разных сборках (gcc версия) показывает одинаково:

```
00408224 I __imp__CryptDecodeObjectEx@32
00408228 I __imp__CryptEncodeObjectEx@28
0040822c I __imp__CryptExportPKCS8@28
00408230 I __imp__CryptExportPublicKeyInfo@20
0040820c I __imp__CryptImportKey@24
00408234 I __imp__CryptImportPublicKeyInfo@16
00408238 I __imp__CryptStringToBinaryA@28
00408218 I __imp__CryptVerifySignatureA@24
```

Comment: В заголовке Decode, а в примере кода - Encode. Вы ничего случайно не перепутали?

Comment: Упс, поправил..

Comment: А проверить свой код на другом компиляторе не пробовали? MinGW-w64 крайней версии ведёт себя так же? Всё-таки, TDM уже того.

Comment: можно, но для этого надо его поставить.. MinGW-w64, но хотелось бы понять, что тут то не так.

Comment: "Поставить" это значит разархивировать папку на диск и указать в CodeBlocks путь к toolchain. Делается за 5 минут. Что-то не так может быть либо с компилятором, либо с вашим кодом. Если mingw так же не осилит, значит проблема в вашем коде и вам надо привести пример вашего кода (не одну строчку).

Comment: Да, спасибо, я в курсе как ставить :) сейчас выкрою время, займусь..

Comment: Обновил, с использованием gcc 8.10

Comment: *"Приложение проходит 22 цикла"* - в `RSA_write_key` нету циклов. Покажите код, как вы её используете. Очевидно, что ошибка в вашем коде, который вы так упорно скрываете.

Comment: Дебагер проходит на функции 22 цикла, GDB, в окне Stack Call отображается чего он там внутри функции вызывает. Это и имелось в виду под словом 'цикл'. В gdb логе видно это, специально привел. Код собирается тот что указан, умешленно не стал приводить свой, дабы исключить дебаты о неработоспособности :)

Comment: Протестировал. Падало в дебаге пока в `RSA_Open` не заменил `malloc` на `calloc`. После этого, генерирование ключей происходит без ошибок. Win8.1 x64, gcc 7.3.0 (MSYS2), сборка 32 bit.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я это везде по коду тоже поправил, malloc на calloc, с этого и начал, тоже падало :) А мой бинарник у вас запускается? Например с ключем `-g 2048` ?

Comment: Ваш бинарник падает на `RSA_write_key`. Вот мой проект в CB, может чем-то поможет https://yadi.sk/d/ZsDwLuBRewH7oQ

Comment: Да, ваш работает, спасибо за уделенное время. буду далее разбираться что там не так.

Comment: Вообще забавно что и у вас падает, пораздумав маленько решил я.. :) значит дело не в версии cryp32.dll, а скорее всего дело то ли в интерпретации параметров функции gcc, либо dllimport что то не совсем то импортирует..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо `@Zed` за помощь, изучив в редакторе свой проект.cbp и сравнив его с вашим - нашел отличие, оно и поставило ситуацию на место, все заработало!
Это был флаг компилятора `-fexceptions`, который в Code::Blocks никак не отражается, и вероятно устанавливается им по умолчанию :)

[почему это происходит](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_chr1418137380191.htm)

> Если исключение распространяется на функцию, которая была
>   скомпилирована без поддержки исключений, программа завершается.